# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in grid view

Tags: asp.net

```
RadioButton yes = null;
RadioButton no = null;
GridViewRow row = GV_College_Information1.Rows[i];
yes = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("yes");
no = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("no");

if (yes.Checked && yes!=null)
```

I'm getting exception at this statement . Anyone plz guide me through this

Comment: please try to debug your code more closely before asking for help..

Answer (score 0):

Remove second condition from if block or you can see sample code below like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < GV_College_Information1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        RadioButton yes = (GV_College_Information1.Rows[i].FindControl("grdRdo")) as RadioButton;
        if (yes.Checked == true)
        {

        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Removing null-checking of object can't help prevent `NullReferenceException` throwing when accessing this object properties.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that by some reason this code `(RadioButton)row.FindControl("yes")` returns `null`.

You have tried to handle this situation by `if (yes.Checked && yes!=null)` but in fact you've done it incorrectly (wrong order of confitions to check).

It should be `if (yes!=null && yes.Checked)` instead.

The reason is: if you attempting to access property of null object - you'll get that exception, so **first** you have to check if object is not null and only then access its properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

If the radiobutton with `id="row"` really exists in the `row`, you wont get the null reference exception in your if statement. But anyway, you should make the null checking prior to yes.Checked in your if statement, as Andy Korneyev points out.

```
yes = (RadioButton)(row.FindControl("yes"));
if (yes!=null && yes.Checked)
```

Comment: you should also see Andy Korneyev's answer, and make sure you make the null checking prior to `yes.Checked` in your if statement

Comment: He is not casting `row` to `RadioButton`. In fact `(RadioButton)row.FindControl("yes")` is absolute equivalent to `(RadioButton)(row.FindControl("yes"))`. If it was cast of row - it would be written as `((RadioButton)row).FindControl("yes")`. Also , in the case of casting row to radiobutton it should be `InvalidCastException`, not `null` as result of cast.